# Unusual Symfony error I dont understand

Tags: php, symfony

One of my colleagues has just seen the following error when attempting to load our website:

```
ErrorException: Warning: session_start(): open (/tmp/sess_4h4kjh4ui4h478h48h44g02,O_RDWR) failed:No space left on device(28) in /var/www/website/symfony/src/symfony/component/HttpFoundation/SessionStorage/NativeSessionStorage.php line 87
```

No one else seems to see this error, and my server is only using 18% of its disk space.

Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

Your /tmp is probably on another partition, which is 100% full.

Linux systems are often set up like that, with /tmp not being part of the / filesystem.

Comment: So what do I do? Is it safe to delete everything out of /tmp? How do I increase its partition?

Comment: Check http://superuser.com/questions/407475/increase-tmp-size-centos, or perhaps ask your own question there - it's a bit out of scope for SO I think.